# SSIS Package Fails due to ADO NET source could not create connection manager with Netsuite

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ado.net, etl, netsuite

I've deployed some SSIS projects to SSIS Server catalog, which everyone runs perfectly in the Visual Studio environment and can connect and retrieve data from NETSUITE using the ADO NET provider (Netsuite AnalyticsConnect Data Provider) but when I try to automate the package in the SSIS Server, the job doesn't run and give the error:

[image]

Is there a way to work around this? I am not having any other errors or something related when the connection is with the local SQL Server.

Comment: Did you install ADO NET provider (Netsuite AnalyticsConnect Data Provider) on the SSIS run-time server?

Comment: Did you register the driver NetSuite.SuiteAnalyticsConnect.dll file in the Global Assembly Cache on the SSIS run-time server? https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_3998994424.html#bridgehead_4599371108

Comment: actually can't believe that I miss register the  driver .dll. Remembered that I done that in the another PC, where is the Visual Studio running. Thanks, please post this as your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a two step process:

1. Install ADO NET provider (Netsuite AnalyticsConnect Data Provider)
   on the SSIS run-time server.
2. Register the driver *NetSuite.SuiteAnalyticsConnect.dll* file in the
   Global Assembly Cache on the SSIS run-time server.

For the reference: [Connecting with the ADO.NET Data Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_3998994424.html#bridgehead_4599371108)

Comment: 3. Ensure the package runs in a 32bit runtime if required by the NetSuite driver.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642410/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-ssis-package-in-32-bit-runtime-from-another-project-whic